# Unparseable date 'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss' during importing ARFF file

Tags: java, date, datetime, weka, unparseable

I'm trying to import an arff file using Java Weka Api but it gives me an error:

```
DataSource source = new DataSource("C:/Users/user/Documenti/file.arff");
Instances dataset = source.getDataSet();
```

> java.io.IOException: unparseable date: 2014-03-30 02:00:00, read Token[2014-03-30 02:00:00], line 8001
>       at weka.core.converters.ArffLoader$ArffReader.errorMessage(ArffLoader.java:354)
>       at weka.core.converters.ArffLoader$ArffReader.getInstanceFull(ArffLoader.java:744)
>       at weka.core.converters.ArffLoader$ArffReader.getInstance(ArffLoader.java:545)
>       at weka.core.converters.ArffLoader$ArffReader.readInstance(ArffLoader.java:514)
>       at weka.core.converters.ArffLoader$ArffReader.readInstance(ArffLoader.java:500)
>       at weka.core.converters.ArffLoader.getDataSet(ArffLoader.java:1240)
>       at weka.core.converters.ConverterUtils$DataSource.getDataSet(ConverterUtils.java:269)

The structure of the arff file is the following:

```
@attribute id numeric
@attribute idsito numeric
@attribute lat numeric
@attribute lon numeric
@attribute data date 'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss'
```

The line 8001 of the arff file is the following:

```
265294,5,40.802742,16.894081,'2014-03-30 02:00:00'
```

The import of previous instances is fine but I do not understand why exactly at line 8001 that gives me problems.

Answer (score 3):

I think the data is invalid. 30-March 2014 was the last Sunday in March which is the date where the Daylight Savings Time change occurs in many [Countries](https://www.timeanddate.com/time/dst/2014.html): e.g. the clock may be set from 1:00 to 3:00 - depending on your time-zone of course.

So maybe you must tell your library which time-zone to use.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Now I try to change the clock from 2:00 to 3:00